# Prove $P(A) \geq P(B)$ when $B \cup C = A$ and $B \cap C = \emptyset$

Tags: probability

Consider three events, $A, B$ and $C$, such that:
$$B \cup  C = A,$$
$$B \cap C = \emptyset.$$
Prove that $P(A) \geqslant P(B).$

I know that $B$ and $C$ are disjoint, so $P(B \cup C) = P(B) + P(C).$ But I am unsure on how to continue to solve this question.

Comment: What do these dots menan? Like what do the $\cdot$s in $\cdot B\cup C = A\cdot B\cap C$ stand for?

Comment: If $P(A) = P(B)+P(C)$ and $P(C) \geq 0$ then $P(A) \geq P(A)-P(C) = P(B)$

Answer (score 1):

You have almost solved the problem.

As $B ∪ C = A$ $\implies$ $P(B ∪ C) = P(A)$$\implies$ $P(B)+P(C) = P(A)$.

Also, $ 0\leq P(C) $$\leq 1$.